# Backbone model.unset not removing property

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am not sure why the `model.unset()` event is not firing.

I am setting a model's view based on input blur events.  When an input has a value the model is set with the value.  If that value is than removed from the form I want to delete the property from the model but my `model.unset()` is not working and I am not sure why.

Here is my current code using Backbone

JS:

```
var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({    
});

var theModel = new TheModel();

var TheFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.js-form',

    initialize: function() {
        this.model = theModel; 

    },

    template: _.template( $('#form-template').html() ),

    render: function() {

        this.$el.html( this.template({settings: this.model.toJSON()}) );

        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'blur .js-input': 'updateModel'  
    },

    updateModel: function(e) {
        var name = e.target.name,
            value = e.target.value;

        if (value !== '') {
            this.model.set(name, value);
        }
        // Why does unset not get fired here? 
        else if ( this.model.has(name) && this.model.get(name) === '' ) {
            this.model.unset(name);   
        }
    }

});

var TheOutputView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.js-output',

    initialize: function() {
        this.model = theModel;  

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    template: _.template( $('#output-template').html() ),

    render: function() {

        this.$el.html( this.template({settings: this.model.toJSON()}) );

        return this;
    },

});

var theFormView = new TheFormView();
theFormView.render();

var theOutputView = new TheOutputView();
theOutputView.render();
```

HTML and templates:

```
<div class="js-form">
</div>
<div class="js-output">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="form-template">
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="" method="Post">
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="js-input" id="firstName" name="f_Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="js-input" id="lastName" name="l_Name" />
        </div>
    </form>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="output-template">
    <div>
        f_Name = <%- settings.f_Name %>
        <br />
        l_Name = <%- settings.l_Name %>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple logic error - you should not include `this.model.get(name) === ''` in your check.

In fact, the preceding `if` means that you cannot set the Model's `name` attribute to an empty String. Therefore, unless you could set it to an empty String elsewhere in your application, the `else if` condition can *never* be met.

This should work as you expect:

```
if (value !== '') {
  this.model.set(name, value);
}
else if ( this.model.has(name)) {
  this.model.unset(name);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought that I should check for both if the property exists, and if that property is `''` but I guess I don't need too.

Comment: Nope - the preceding `if` means you never set `name` to an empty String in the first place.